# insert php code in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

```
function search_num_rows($param){
        $company_name=$param['company_name'];
        $loan_no=$param['loan_no'];

        $q = $this->db->query("select Count(0) as num_rows
                                from contact_new 
                                inner join  companies c on contact_new.company_id = c.id 
                                inner join history on contact_new.id = history.receiver_email 
                                inner join escalation_level on contact_new.escalation_level_id = escalation_level.id
                                inner join departments on contact_new.departmend_id = departments.id
                                WHERE  loan_no= '$loan_no' if($company_name){ AND company_name= '$company_name'} ")->result();
    return $q[0]->num_rows;
}
```

can i insert the php code as i done in where clause.Is there any other way to do this without using active records.

Comment: is there a particular reason you don't want to use active records to insert?

Comment: Can you? Have you tried? What was the error, if any?

Comment: Don't forget to escape.

Comment: Yep, try first and then show us errors, bugs.

Comment: @kkhuge Error Number: 1064  skilled i am not comfortable with joins usind active records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually very easy:

```
function search_num_rows($param){
        $company_name = (isset($param['company_name']) && !empty($param['company_name']) ? " AND company_name = '$param[company_name]'" : '');
        $loan_no=$param['loan_no'];

        $q = $this->db->query("select Count(0) as num_rows
                                from contact_new 
                                inner join  companies c on contact_new.company_id = c.id 
                                inner join history on contact_new.id = history.receiver_email 
                                inner join escalation_level on contact_new.escalation_level_id = escalation_level.id
                                inner join departments on contact_new.departmend_id = departments.id
                                WHERE  loan_no= '$loan_no' $company_name")->result();
    return $q[0]->num_rows;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to escape. SQL injection can bite you.